# Difference between deployment through REST and Deployment through Process Application in Camunda

Tags: camunda

As per the recommendation given in below link, we can use deploy via REST only when it is independent of java classes (highlighted part) so if my process has Java delegates and Java listeners then I can't/shouldn't deploy the process via REST ? Or even if I deploy such process via REST, it won't work ?

Please advise.

https://camunda.com/blog/2020/04/how-to-choose-the-right-camunda-architecture/

Deploy via REST: you can simply use Camunda’s REST API to send the process model to the engine. This is often done for the External Task Pattern or ***in cases where the model is not dependent on any local artifacts (e.g. Java Classes)***

Deploy via Process Application: In this case you would locally build and compile an application containing your process(es) and any other required artifacts and then deploy that to the same application service that contains the engine. The engine will automatically deploy what it finds in the application

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The deployment via REST can be used in any case. However, if your process model uses Java classes, then those classes need to exist on your server, otherwise Camunda will not be able to find your delegate or listeners. If the classes are already deployed, then deploying model changes that do not need new or updates classes will be fine. If you change classes, then a byte code deployment will be required. If you restart the server anyway, then deploying automatically via the process application is convenient. You can also deploy through the process application when deploying updated byte code but deploy via REST API when you just want to try deploy model changes not requiring code updates.

These days the recommendation is not to work with Java Delegate and listeners, but to treat Camunda as a black box (remote engine) and have your delegate code in external workers instead. This way your custom code is separated from the engine and you will never need a server restart to apply changes to  model or integration code (You will still have the option to deploy from the now external process application code though). This architecture is not only advisable to decouple your custom code from Camunda, independent of programming language, easier scalale, and more in line with modern micro service architectures, but it also puts you in a better position for a potential future Camunda 8 migration.

Also see:

- https://docs.camunda.io/docs/components/best-practices/architecture/deciding-about-your-stack-c7/#customize-your-stack
- https://docs.camunda.io/docs/guides/migrating-from-camunda-platform-7/#prepare-for-smooth-migrations
- https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.19/user-guide/process-engine/external-tasks/

Comment: Hi @rob2universe

I had a war file with BPMN+JAVA Delegates+Java Listeners deployed on the server then I deployed a war file containing only the updated BPMN model. The BPMN got deployed successfully and I am able to see it on cockpit. But when I start the process instance, I get the following error.

"message": "Cannot instantiate process definition df80297d-f894-11ed-9df7-005056bedd0d: ENGINE-09008 Exception while instantiating class 'com.project.delegates.EventListener': ENGINE-09017 Cannot load class 'com.project.delegates.EventListener': com.project.delegates.EventListener"

Comment: Hi @rob2universe

This is the same issue mentioned in the below link and where Niall recommended to keep the war with Java code and BPMN together and avoid separate deployment of BPMN using REST or war with process app

https://forum.camunda.io/t/exception-while-starting-a-new-bpmn-process-instance/7861/10

But I can't understand the rootcause of this issue. When the Java classes are already deployed on the server then why the updated BPMN is not able to find the Java classes ?

In theory, the separate BPMN deployment without any Java classes should work but it's not working, why ?

Comment: You deployed 2 WAR files? The Camunda job executor is running using the classloader of its own WAR. It cannot see classes which are not in the same WAR.

Comment: Yes, I have 2 separate war files. One with all the java components (Delegates and listeners) and Other one is only with BPMN files and Process Application Class,processes.xml etc. Will this combination of 2 separate war files won't work ?

Comment: No, if you do not use external workers but JavaDelegate and listeners, then the classes need to be deployed in the same classloader as the process engine. Being able to separate custom code from the engine is one of the reasons I listed above for the external task approach. You eithe rneed to switch to external task+worker or bundle the lasses and the engine in the same war. (this has nothing to do with model deployment, it is about where the engine's job executor is running)